# Calling Dataset static method does not work in Spark Shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql

I a newbie in Scala, so I apologize in advance if the solution is trivial.

I'm currently trying to execute a query in Spark Shell where I am modifying the logical plan of a dataset. Here is the sample of my code where I am struggling :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val newPlan = ...
val newDS = Dataset.ofRows(spark, newPlan)
```

When I am running this, I get the following error message:

```
<console>:41: error: not found: value Dataset
   val newDS = Dataset.ofRows(spark, newPlan)
```

When trying to specify the package in the declaration:

```
scala> val newDS = org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.ofRows(spark, newPlan)
```

I get this:

```
<console>:41: error: object Dataset in package sql cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.sql
       val newDS = org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.ofRows(spark, newPlan)
```

I also tried `import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset`, `import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset._` or `import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.*` but none of those worked.

I'm using Spark 2.1.0. Thank you in advance for your help.

## Edit

The answer is, the `ofRows` method of the `Dataset` class is a scala private method. But it is accessible from Java because of the automatic conversion Scala/Java code (and appears in the Javadoc).
So we are technically not supposed to use this method, but it is accidentally accessible through the Java API.
I wanted to perform logical plan changes because I am trying to implement run injection-safe dynamic SQL query. But I will try to find a less hacky way for achieving this goal.

Comment: Dataset.ofRows is a private method. And datasets are created either by defining encoders or by defining case classes. Thats not a way to create a dataset.

Comment: I see, thank you. Indeed I checked the Spark source code, and it's a private method. 
But it appears in the Javadoc, and it looks like we can call it from Java. Does somebody know why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, the ofRows method of the Dataset class is a scala private method. But it is accessible from Java because of the automatic conversion Scala/Java code (and appears in the Javadoc). So we are technically not supposed to use this method, but it is accidentally accessible through the Java API. I wanted to perform logical plan changes because I am trying to implement run injection-safe dynamic SQL query. But I will try to find a less hacky way for achieving this goal.